# is it posible to make multiple facebook share button with different title description on same page dynamically?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm making a web page which has many sections of news inside ,and each of section box has Facebook share button that responses different title ,description and images with same url.and the user must be able to add/remove/edit a section of news dynamically. So, we found using share.php with passing parameter is usable but now It doesn't work because of new version. So,I'm finding other solution.